# What is conditional probability?

Tags: probability-theory

[image: Table utilizing Conditional Entropy]

I've been looking online and through a couple youtube videos but I cannot understand how exactly conditional entropy is being applied here. From what I'm understanding is that p(Y=1 | X=1) is 0 because of (1,1) on this table being 0 at that point, but then p(y=2 | X=1) = 1, which is where I'm getting lost because I thought that would equal 3/4? Basically I'm lost on what p(x|y) means exactly, could I get an explanation using this particular example?

Comment: p(x|y) is the probability of observing x when it is known that y has occurred. E.g. probability of rain vs. probability of rain when there are clouds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one definition of conditional probability:

> $\Pr[A|B]$ is the probability that $A$ happens given that $B$ happens.

Another definition just gives a formula:

> $$ \Pr[A|B] = \frac{\Pr[A \cap B]}{\Pr[B]}. $$

Let's see why $\Pr[Y = 2|X = 1] = 1$. If $X = 1$ then it is always the case that $Y = 2$, and so conditioned on $X = 1$, the probability that $Y = 2$ is $1$.

We can also see this via the formula:
$$
\Pr[Y = 2|X = 1] = \frac{\Pr[Y = 2, X = 1]}{\Pr[X = 1]} = \frac{3/4}{0 + 3/4} = 1.
$$
Here $\Pr[A,B]$ is a commonly used notation for $\Pr[A \cap B]$, which is the probability that both $A$ and $B$ happen at the same time.